# gpiozero vs rpi.gpio library Performance + Control

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am concerned about the pros and cons of using gpiozero over the old rpi.gpio library, is there any performance difference or lower-level control difference?

I read this forum and it didn't really answer my question
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204466

what I got from that forums was that it was a wrapper around the standard rpi library, typically from my programming experience wrappers tend to  be slower and provide less flexibility in exchange for ease of use

however, since that wasn't specified in the forums and I do not know if the performance difference is small-big its hard to know which one I should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why Is GPIO Zero's Approach Better?**

It is easy to read and short as possible. The gpiozero module always uses Broadcom GPIO numbering to identify a GPIO, so there is no setup necessary. There is a little explanation for that:

> BOARD numbering might seem simpler but I'd say it leads new users to think all the pins are general purpose---and they're not. Connect an LED to pin 11, why not connect some more to pins 1, 2, 3 and 4? Well 1 is 3V3. 2 and 4 are 5V. A lack of awareness of what the purpose of the pins is can be dangerous.

**Is GPIO Zero Actually Better?**

> On the one hand, removing the setup code is excellent for beginners and seasoned coders alike. Writing code is more straightforward and quicker. On the other hand, knowing exactly what is going on is important for learning.

I found this description in [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/gpio-zero-raspberry-pi/). So I think if you know what you do or if you want to see how it works I would use gpiozero. But if you want to set all pins yourself I would use rpi.gpio.